# Mini-Game Help- Not printing after Defining function

Tags: python, function

```
import time
import random
inventory = [""]
gold = 0
fish1 = "Mackarel"
fish2 = "Cod"
fish3 = "Salmon"
fish4 = "Herring"
fish5 = "Tuna"
trash1 = "Old Shoe"
trash2 = "Plastic Bag"
trash3 = "Rusted Empty Box"
trash4 = "Plank Fragment"
special1 = "Ring"
fish1_range = range(1,3)
fish2_range = range(3,5)
fish3_range = range(5,7)
fish4_range = range(7,9)
fish5_range = range(9,11)
trash1_range = range(11,16)
trash2_range = range(16,21)
trash3_range = range(21,26)
trash4_range = range(26,31)
special1_range = range(31,32)

print "~~~~WELCOME TO FISHING~~~~"
time.sleep(2)
print "Loading Version 0.2 ..."
time.sleep(2)
print "In this current version the last item in your inventory is sold."
print "To execute another function, for example fish twice you have to wait 20 seconds"
print "This means at the start it will take 20 seconds to load aswell."
def action_function(): #defining action start
    action_function()
    chance = random.randrange(1,31)
    action = raw_input("Do you want to .sell or .fish?")
    if action == "sell":
        if inventory.index(1) == fish1:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 5
            print "You have sold a Mackarel for 5 gold coins!"
            action_function()
        if inventory.index(1) == fish2:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 5
            print "You have sold a Cod for 5 gold coins!"
            action_function()
        if inventory.index(1) == fish3:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 5
            print "You have sold a Salmon for 5 gold coins!"
            action_function()
        if inventory.index(1) == fish4:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 5
            print "You have sold a Herring for 5 gold coins!"
            action_function()
        if inventory.index(1) == fish5:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 5
            print "You have sold a Tuna for 5 gold coins!"
            action_function()
        if inventory.index(1) == trash1:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 1
            print "You have recycled an Old Shoe for 1 gold coin."
            action_function()
        if inventory.index(1) == trash2:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 1
            print "You have recycled an Plastic Bag for 1 gold coin."
            action_function()
        if inventory.index(1) == trash3:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 1
            print "You have recycled an Rusted Empty Box for 1 gold coin."
            action_function()
        if inventory.index(1) == trash4:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 1
            print "You have recycled an Old Shoe for 1 gold coin."
            action_function()
        if inventory.index(1) == special1:
            inventory.pop(1)
            gold + 10
            print "A rare find, 10 gold pieces will serve you!"
            action_function()
    if action == "fish":
        if random.randrange == fish1_range:
            inventory.append(fish1)
            print "You have reeled in a Mackarel!"
            action_function()
        if random.randrange == fish2_range:
            inventory.append(fish2)
            print "You have reeled in a Cod!"
            action_function()
        if random.randrange == fish3_range:
            inventory.append(fish3)
            print "You have reeled in a Salmon!"
            action_function()
        if random.randrange == fish4_range:
            inventory.append(fish4)
            print "You have reeled in a Herring!"
            action_function()
        if random.randrange == fish5_range:
            inventory.append(fish5)
            print "You have reeled in a Tuna!"
            action_function()
        if random.randrange == trash1_range:
            inventory.append(trash1)
            print "You have reeled in a...Shoe..."
            action_function()
        if random.randrange == trash2_range:
            inventory.append(trash2)
            print "You have reeled in a...Plastic Bag..."
            action_function()
        if random.randrange == trash3_range:
            inventory.append(trash3)
            print "You have reeled in a...Rusted Empty Box..."
            action_function()
        if random.randrange == trash4_range:
            inventory.append(trash4)
            print "You have reeled in a...Plank Fragment..."
            action_function()
        if random.randrange == special1_range:
            inventory.append(special1)
            print "You find a slightly dirty ring, after clearing the dirt it appears quite nice."
            action_function()
    if action == "inventory":
        print inventory
        action_function()
```

So i've tried hundreds of times now, I tried using loops, and tons of other stuff and nothing seems to work how I want it to. Most of the time it just goes blank after the first part when I define a function, it might have gone further but I can't tell. Also as you can tell from this awkward problem I am new to programming, Please help me, if someone could just explain why it only prints the text up to the defining of the action function.

Comment: Did you *call* the function?

Comment: Your function calls itself as the first line; if you do call it you'll get an infinite recursion error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call the function after defining it:

```
action_function()
```

Remember that Python defines blocks by indentation, so put the `action_function()` line on the same indentation level as the `def action_function():` line.

You also want to remove the `action_function()` call from the first line of the function.

Some other tips:

- Don't create `name_x` series of variables. Use lists instead:

  ```
  fish = ["Mackarel", "Cod", "Salmon", "Herring", "Tuna"]
  ```
- If you want to add 5 to the `gold` variable, you need to store it back in that variable:

  ```
  gold = gold + 5
  ```

  or, shorter:

  ```
  gold += 5
  ```
- The `.index(1)` function looks for the list index of the value `1`; you probably wanted to use indexing directly instead:

  ```
  if inventory[0] == something:
  ```

  Remember that Python list indexes start at *0*, not 1.

  If you use lists for your fish and trash variables, you can do:

  ```
  if inventory[0] in fish:
      sold = inventory.pop(0)
      gold += 5
      print "You have sold a", sold, "for 5 gold coins!"
  ```

  and eliminate all the extra `if` branches.
- Instead of using recursion, use a loop:

  ```
  while True:
      # print, get input, do actions
      # when done, use `break` to stop the loop.
  ```